# How do I call variables from a Java class in another Class

Tags: java, database, user-interface, inheritance, actionlistener

If I have a class with prepared statements, how do I call them when a user presses a button.

```
class updateeButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        name = displayName.getText();
        price = bookPrice.getText();
        Queries update = new Queries();???????????????????
    }
}
```

Prepared Statement in different class

```
public int update(String price, String name) throws SQLException {
        ps2.setString(1, name);
        ps2.setString(2, price);
        System.out.print("Update - ");
        return ps2.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object and invoke the update method with parameters as shown below:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        name = displayName.getText();
        price = bookPrice.getText();
        Queries update = new Queries(); 
        update.update(price, name);//invoke the method using the object
}
```

Comment: In addition you can instantiate the class in construtor or pass to constructor instead of creating inside the method to be more OO.

Comment: How would you do that? How did a display the returned valued. thanks

Comment: Any advice please